# Ajax not passing correct data to $_POST on responding php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've got an ajax function:

```
$('#addSiteButton').on('click',function() {
  let addSiteOption = $('#enterNewWebsiteLink').val();
  const form = new FormData();

 form.append('addSiteOption', addSiteOption);

 $.ajax({
  url: "includes/submit_site.php",
  data: { 'data': form },
  method: "POST",
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  enctype: false,
  cache: false,
  datatype: "text",

 success: function (response, data) {
  }
});
```

My PHP file looks just like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['data'])) {
 $websitelink = $_POST['addSiteOption'];
}
```

my HTML looks like this:

```
<input type="url" form="addsite" class="enterNewWebsiteLink" 
  id="enterNewWebsiteLink"
  name="enterwebsitelink"
  placeholder="Enter A New Website">
```

The error that I am getting is: `Warning: Undefined array key "data"`
I've tried outputting the variable `addSiteOption` and it outputs the URL correctly.

The frustrating thing, I've been checking/copying this against a previous project I did that I got it working in, and I can't make any difference between them now.

I get a 200 response from the server for the page.

Comment: You can't serialize a FormData.

Comment: Why are you using `FormData` if you're not uploading a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't serialize `FormData`, and `processData: false` tells jQuery not to try to serialize the `data:` option.

You should just pass the `FormData` as the `data:` option. Then the keys of the `FormData` will become the `$_POST` keys.

JS:

```
$('#addSiteButton').on('click',function() {
  let addSiteOption = $('#enterNewWebsiteLink').val();
  const form = new FormData();

 form.append('addSiteOption', addSiteOption);

 $.ajax({
  url: "includes/submit_site.php",
  data: form,
  method: "POST",
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  enctype: false,
  cache: false,
  dataType: "text",

 success: function (response, data) {
  }
});
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['addSiteOption'])) {
 $websitelink = $_POST['addSiteOption'];
}
```

You also had a typo: `datatype:` should be `dataType:`

Comment: Thanks, i checked what i had against what you wrote, and made the changes, but it didn't work, however, when I copied and pasted it, it worked! lol typical! thanks a million